# every k-th digit of a number in c

Tags: arrays, c, integer

Given some natural numbers n and k, my goal is to write a C program that outputs a number formed by every k-th digit of n. I wrote a program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 100
  
void printDigit(int n, int k)
{
    int arr[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int j, r;
  
    while (n != 0) {
        r = n % pow(10,k);
        arr[i] = r;
        i++;
        n = n / pow(10,k);
    }
  
    for (j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
}
  
int main()
{
    int n = 12345678;
    int k = 2;
  
    printDigit(n,k);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says

```
error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'int' and 'double')
   16 |         r = n % pow(10,k);
```

I can't figure out what's the problem. Both `n` and `10^k` are integers and `%` operation should be valid

Comment: `pow`'s signature is `double pow(double, double)` so even though `pow(10, k)` may be representable as an `int` the turn type of the function is `double`...

Comment: `n % pow(10,k)` -> `n % (int)pow(10,k)`. Read about typecasting in your C learning material.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You should round it rather than casting. Sometimes the value could be a tiny bit lower than the integer, and `(int)` will round down.

Comment: And although you can get it to work with `pow()`, the inaccuracies are going to be a huge nuisance to work around, and it's unnecessarily inefficient, to boot (if that matters).  You can do this perfectly well, and more easily in the end, with successive multiplications or divisions by 10.

Comment: k-th starting from the beginning or the end?

Comment: @tstanisl from end