# A number formed by every k-th digit of another number in c

Tags: arrays, c, integer, division

Given some natural numbers n and k, my goal is to write a C program that outputs a number formed by every k-th digit of n. I wrote a program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 100
  
void printDigit(int n, int k)
{
    int arr[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int j, r;
  
    while (n != 0) {
        r = n % (int)pow(10,k);
        arr[i] = r;
        i++;
        n = n / pow(10,k);
    }
  
    for (j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
}
  
int main()
{
    int n = 12345678;
    int k = 2;
  
    printDigit(n,k);
    return 0;
}
```

My code outputs the same number but partitioned into substrings of length k. Why is that and how can I fix it so that I get the number I wanted?

Comment: *my goal is to write a C program* Then don't tag C++.

Comment: Warning: `pow` operates on floating point numbers and floating point numbers are not precise. You can reasonably expect `pow(10,2)` to result in a close-enough-for-floats 99.99999999999999999999999999, but that won't be rounded up to 100 when you transform it back into an integer. Instead it'll be truncated to 99. When getting exponents of integers prefer to multiply. You won't get any surprises that way, at least not until you overflow the capacity of the integer.

Comment: Fun trick: when you're given a decompose the number into digits problem, Take the input as a string and keep it a string until you've taken it apart. With the input as a string, finding the kth digit is a dead-simple `number_as_string[k]`

Comment: @user4581301: Floating-point numbers are precise and accurate (they are exact). Floating-point operations have rounding errors. Understanding this distinction is essential to analyzing, proving, and debugging floating-point software.

Comment: How does this question differ from [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352012/every-k-th-digit-of-a-number-in-c)?  You're starting to get the same comments here that you did there.

Comment: @SteveSummit same code, but different problem. I tried to update the previous one but soon figured out it's not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is too complicated, but if you want to stick to it:

```
int intpow(int x, int y)
{
    int result = 1;
    while(y--) result *= x;
    return result;
}

void printDigit(int n, int k)
{
    int arr[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int j, r, powv;
  
    while (n != 0) {
        powv = intpow(10,k -1);
        n /= powv;
        if(!n) break;
        r = n % 10;
        arr[i] = r;
        i++;
        n = n / 10;
    }
  
    for (j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Too complicated? Is there any simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

`n % (int)pow(10,k)` is the low-order `k` digits of `n`. If you just want one digit, use `n % 10`.

Since `pow(10, k)` returns a `double`, it might not be an exact integer. You should round it to the nearest integer to do proper division.

```
void printDigit(int n, int k)
{
    int arr[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int j, r;
    int divisor = lround(pow(10, k));
  
    while (n != 0) {
        r = n % 10;
        arr[i] = r;
        i++;
        n = n / divisor;
    }
  
    for (j = i - 1; j > -1; j--) {
        printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work I afraid https://godbolt.org/z/7GEc1c9sb

Comment: I tried to run this code. It doesn't seem to output every k-th digit. I tried moving "n=lround..." line to a place right after "r=n%10;" part, so that it doesn't start by adding the last digit to the array, but  still not successful

Comment: I see the problem. When we divide `12345678` by `100`, it's `123456.78`, which rounds up to `1234567`. We need to round `pow(10,k)`, not the result of division.

Comment: I just tested it, I get 2, 4, 6, 8.

Comment: @Barmar `I just tested it` - no you did not. Try to change k to 3 for example. Still doesn't work

Comment: With k = 3 I got 2 5 8. That's every 3 digits starting from the right.

Comment: he wanted from the left - same as we write from left to rigtht.